# Expected an expression; menu driven function program

Tags: c

I'm having problems calling the function displayArray. It says expected an expression. What am I doing wrong? I don't quite fully understand how calling a function works, any help is appreciated. I'm still working on this program and my only problem right now is calling functions.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define CLS system("cls")
#define FLUSH myFlush()
#define SIZE 100
#define LB 1
#define UB 100

// ProtoType Functions Here
void myFlush();
int loadArray(int num[], int c);
void displayArray(int num[], int c);
void enterAnumber();

main() {
    int userChoice = 0;

    do {
        CLS;
        printf("=======================\n");
        printf("====== MAIN MENU ======\n");
        printf("=======================\n");
        printf("1. Enter a number \n");
        printf("2. Display the sum of all numbers entered \n");
        printf("3. Display Average of numbers entered \n");
        printf("4. Display all numbers entered \n\n");
        printf("5. Quit the program \n\n");
        printf("Enter your selection: ");
        scanf("%i", &userChoice);

        switch (userChoice) {

        case 1: // Enter a number
            enterAnumber();
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 2: // Display the sum of all nums ent
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 3: // Display the average of all nums ent
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 4: // Display all numbers entered
            displayArray(int num[], int c);
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 5: // QUIT THE PROGRAM
            PAUSE;
            break;
        default:
            PAUSE;
            break;
        } // end switch

    } while (userChoice != 4);
    PAUSE;
} // end of main
  //============================================
void enterAnumber() {
    int numbers[SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    // seed the rand function
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    // displayArray(numbers, count); // ArrayStats
    count = loadArray(numbers, count);
}

void displayArray(int num[], int c) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        printf("The number selected: %i\n", num[i]);
    }
    PAUSE;
}

int loadArray(int num[], int c) {
    int result;
    int i;
    int howMany;

    printf("How many numbers do you wish to create: ");
    scanf("%i", &howMany);
    for (i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        num[i] = LB + rand() % (UB - LB + 1);

    result = c + howMany;
    return result;
} // end loadArray

void myFlush() {
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Comment: `displayArray(int num[], int c);` - that isn't a function call. Function calls pass parameters; not declare them. And your entered numbers are local to your `enterAnumber` function anyway, so it seems you have to rearrange some things.

Comment: yep .. @WhozCraig is right ...